# How to reduce a nested object array to get optional content values

Tags: javascript, arrays

There is a nested object array and I have to get all unique refIds, which are existing at any level.

I tried to iterate with for-loops, but it really gets very complicated. And also I don't know how deep the data exactly is.
But is always an `"type": "text"`element with an optional `"marks"` field.

```
[
  {
    "type": "bulletList",
    "content": [
      {
        "type": "listItem",
        "content": [
          {
            "type": "paragraph",
            "content": [
              {
                "type": "text",
                "marks": [ // optional mark
                  { "type": "refId", "attrs": { "refIds": [123, 234] } } // need this values
                ],
                "text": "Item 1"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "listItem",
        "content": [
          {
            "type": "paragraph",
            "content": [
              {
                "type": "text",
                "marks": [{ "type": "refId", "attrs": { "refIds": [987] } }],
                "text": "Item 2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "listItem",
        "content": [
          {
            "type": "paragraph",
            "content": [{ "type": "text", "text": "Item 3" }] // has no mark
          },
          {
            "type": "bulletList", // example for nested child
            "content": [
              {
                "type": "listItem",
                "content": [
                  {
                    "type": "paragraph",
                    "content": [
                      {
                        "type": "text",
                        "marks": [
                          { "type": "refId", "attrs": { "refIds": [876] } }
                        ],
                        "text": "Sub 1"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Output should be

```
["123", "234", "876", "987"]
```

Comment: Could you show us the code you've tried and the result? We might be able to spot where it's going wrong. Whenever you talk about 'nesting', think 'recursion' in your code - a function that handles one level only, and delegates to itself (makes a 'nested' call) to handle deeper levels. That way, your function only cares about the current level and that should simplify it.

Comment: Why isn't `876` in your expected output?

Comment: @NickParsons Yes, you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just walk recursively for arrays and objects and collect the ids into a set:

```js
const walk = (arr, out = new Set) => {
  if(Array.isArray(arr)){
    arr.forEach(r => walk(r, out));
  }else if(arr && typeof arr ==='object'){
    for(const key in arr){
      if(key === 'refIds' && Array.isArray(arr[key])){
        arr[key].forEach(r => out.add(r));
      }else walk(arr[key], out);
    }
  }
  return out;

}

const result = [...walk(arr)];

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
const arr=[{type:"bulletList",content:[{type:"listItem",content:[{type:"paragraph",content:[{type:"text",marks:[{type:"refId",attrs:{refIds:[123,234]}}],text:"Item 1"}]}]},{type:"listItem",content:[{type:"paragraph",content:[{type:"text",marks:[{type:"refId",attrs:{refIds:[987]}}],text:"Item 2"}]}]},{type:"listItem",content:[{type:"paragraph",content:[{type:"text",text:"Item 3"}]},{type:"bulletList",content:[{type:"listItem",content:[{type:"paragraph",content:[{type:"text",marks:[{type:"refId",attrs:{refIds:[876]}}],text:"Sub 1"}]}]}]}]}]}];
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that missing `876` from the output was a mistake, you can use [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) on your array. For each object that you map you can check if its type is `text`, and if it is, look for a `marks` array that you then perform a nested `flatMap` on to transform into an array of ids. Since this inner `.flatMap()` is done in a parent `.flatMap()` the inner array results will be flattened/concatenated into the resulting array that's eventually returned by the parent `.flatMap()` (avoiding nested arrays). Otherwise, if the current object isn't of `type` `text`, then you can perform a recursive call, passing in the `content` of the current object back into the `getRefIds()` function to get the refIds from that nested array (we default `content` to an empty array if it doesn't exist, which gets ignored when eventually flattened/merged into the resulting array). Finally, you can convert the result into a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and then back into an array to deduplicate:

```js
const arr = [ { "type": "bulletList", "content": [ { "type": "listItem", "content": [ { "type": "paragraph", "content": [ { "type": "text", "marks": [ { "type": "refId", "attrs": { "refIds": [123, 234] } } ], "text": "Item 1" } ] } ] }, { "type": "listItem", "content": [ { "type": "paragraph", "content": [ { "type": "text", "marks": [{ "type": "refId", "attrs": { "refIds": [987] } }], "text": "Item 2" } ] } ] }, { "type": "listItem", "content": [ { "type": "paragraph", "content": [{ "type": "text", "text": "Item 3" }]  }, { "type": "bulletList", "content": [ { "type": "listItem", "content": [ { "type": "paragraph", "content": [ { "type": "text", "marks": [ { "type": "refId", "attrs": { "refIds": [876] } } ], "text": "Sub 1" } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ];

const getRefIds = (arr) => {
  return arr.flatMap(({type, content = [], marks = []}) => type === "text" 
    ? marks.flatMap(mark => mark.attrs.refIds) // add an additional `.filter(mark => mark.type === "refId")` if you can have other types in `marks`
    : getRefIds(content)
  );
}

const res = Array.from(new Set(getRefIds(arr)));
console.log(res);
```

If your data is large, then you might want to avoid creating intermediate arrays (as done in the above example with each recursive call by the `.flatMap`s), and so you can try and use a nested recursive function like below to help:

```js
const arr = [ { "type": "bulletList", "content": [ { "type": "listItem", "content": [ { "type": "paragraph", "content": [ { "type": "text", "marks": [ { "type": "refId", "attrs": { "refIds": [123, 234] } } ], "text": "Item 1" } ] } ] }, { "type": "listItem", "content": [ { "type": "paragraph", "content": [ { "type": "text", "marks": [{ "type": "refId", "attrs": { "refIds": [987] } }], "text": "Item 2" } ] } ] }, { "type": "listItem", "content": [ { "type": "paragraph", "content": [{ "type": "text", "text": "Item 3" }]  }, { "type": "bulletList", "content": [ { "type": "listItem", "content": [ { "type": "paragraph", "content": [ { "type": "text", "marks": [ { "type": "refId", "attrs": { "refIds": [876] } } ], "text": "Sub 1" } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ];

const getRefIds = (arr) => {
  const refIds = new Set();
  const searchContent = (contentArr) => {
    for(const {type, content = [], marks = []} of contentArr) {
      if (type === "text")
        marks.forEach(mark => {
          if (mark.type === "refId") // again, add this if only if required.
            mark.attrs.refIds.forEach(id => refIds.add(id));
        });
      else
        searchContent(content);
    }
  } 
  searchContent(arr);
  return Array.from(refIds); // convert the set into an array
}

const res = getRefIds(arr);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: What would be "large" data? Are 100 items large?

Comment: No, I’d consider that relatively small. Probably anything more than 10k, but that’s really just an arbitrary number. Mainly an amount where you feel like the program needs to be optimised as it’s running slow.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAllIds(data) {
const refIds = new Set();

function iterate(el) {
    if (el.type === "text" && el.marks) {
        el.marks.forEach(mark => {
            if (mark.type === "refId" && mark.attrs && mark.attrs.refIds) {
                mark.attrs.refIds.forEach(refId => refIds.add(refId));
            }
        });
    }

    if (el.content) {
        el.content.forEach(child => iterate(child));
    }
}

data.forEach(item => iterate(item));
return [...refIds];
```

}